# Is any blow-up of smooth subvarieties always an extremal contraction?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety and $Z$ be a smooth subvariety of $X$. 
Take the blow-up $\pi: Y \to X$ of $X$ along $Z$. 
Then I want to know whether $\pi$ is the contraction of an extremal face of 
$\bar{\mathrm{NE}}(Y)$.

In particular, is the exceptional locus $\mathrm{Exc}(\pi)$ covered by curves which 
have negative intersection numbers with $K_Y$?

Comment: The fibers of $\pi$ on the exceptional divisor are projective spaces.  The curve class of the lines in those projective spaces spans a $K_Y$-negative extremal ray.